# Vue App Routing not working when served via Nginx Proxy

Tags: vue.js, nginx

I am serving a Vue App via proxy_pass from my Nginx server. Here's my config looks like:

```
location /iframe/reports/ {
  proxy_pass http://reports-frontend/reports;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;  
}

location ^~ /js/ {
  proxy_pass http://reports-frontend/js/;
}

location ^~ /css/ {
  proxy_pass http://reports-frontend/css/;
}
```

My Vue App is running inside a Nginx docker container with the following configuration:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}
```

When I request localhost:8080/iframe/reports I am able to get the index.html and assets needed. But the routing seems not to be working. Why is that so?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably you've missed a trailing slash `/` at proxy_pass, like `proxy_pass http://reports-frontend/reports/;` ?

Comment: Are you sure that Vue App is properly configured to accept requests on that routes: `/reports/my_route` ?

Comment: @mgsxman I added a trailing slash but still doesn't work. In my vue the route should be 
/reports/product-summary